# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS Brightness

Tags: 12.04

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS but the brightness won't work. Not from settings, not from the hotkeys. Is there anything I can do to fix this? I have Dell Inspiron 15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your video card a GeForce GT 525M or GeForce GT 520M? You can download linux driver for Ubuntu 64 bit from here. Installing the driver can be a pain in the back but if you are familiar with installing video driver it should not be such a big problem:

http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/73666/en-us

http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/73966/en-us

If you are using Ubuntu 32 bit you need the Linux 32bit video drivers from Nvidia.